# VBA Filter Table and Copy Subset of Resulting Columns to Clipboard

Tags: vba, excel, filter, copy-paste

I am trying to automatically copy a subset of rows and columns from a source table into the clipboard for use in other applications. I am creating the filter on the header of the table and filtering the rows correctly but do not know how to then select the subset of columns in the order I want. The source table is Columns A - L and I want to copy out Columns C, I, H and F in that order to the clipboard after applying the filter. Some code (minus the copy part) is included below.

```
Sub exportExample()
    Dim header As Range
    Dim srcCol As Range

    Set header = [A5:L5]

    header.AutoFilter
    header.AutoFilter 12, "Example", xlFilterValues

    'Copy out columns C, I, H and F of the resulting table in that order
End Sub
```

I can figure out how to copy the columns but can't figure out how to get them in the order I want. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you may have to copy them column-by-column into the order you want on another area of the sheet (or a new sheet), then copy that whole range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so that you shouldn't have any problem understanding it.

**LOGIC**:

1. Filter the data
2. Create a Temp Sheet
3. Copy filtered data to temp sheet
4. Delete unnecessary columns (A,B,D,E,G,J,K,L)
5. Rearrange relevant columns (C,F,H,I) TO C,I,H and F
6. Delete Temp Sheet in the end (IMP: Read notes at the end of the code)

**CODE (*Tried And Tested*)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim rRange As Range, rngToCopy As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the Last Row
        lRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your range for autofilter
        Set rRange = .Range("A5:L" & lRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Filter, copy visible rows to temp sheet
        With rRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Example"

            '~~> This is required to get the visible range
            ws.Rows("1:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True

            Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

            Set wsTemp = Sheets.Add

            rngToCopy.Copy wsTemp.Range("A1")

            '~~> Unhide the rows
            ws.Rows("1:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Re arrange columns in Temp sheet so that we get C, I, H and F
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A:B,D:E,G:G,J:L").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("D:D").Cut
        .Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Columns("D:D").Cut
        .Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngToCopy = .Range("A1:D" & lRow)

        Debug.Print rngToCopy.Address

        '~~> Copy the range to clipboard
        rngToCopy.Copy
    End With

    'NOTE
    '
    '~~> Once you have copied the range to clipboard, do the necessary
    '~~> actions and then delete the temp sheet. Do not delete the
    '~~> sheet before that. An alternative would be to use the APIs
    '~~> to place the range in the clipboard so you can safely delete
    '~~> the sheet before performing any actions. This will not clear
    '~~> clear the range if the sheet is immediately deleted.
    '
    '

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

Sheet1 before the code is run

[image]

Temp sheet with filtered data

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

To remove borders you can add this code to the above code

```
With rngToCopy
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
end with
```

Put the above code after the line `Debug.Print rngToCopy.Address`

Comment: This works well, thanks! I'll need to modify the code to strip off some of the formatting (borders from the table) but I should be able to figure it out. Would it be a quick change to not copy the header row to the temporary worksheet?

Comment: Change this `rngToCopy.Copy wsTemp.Range("A1")` to `rngToCopy.Copy` and in the next line put this `wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I figured out how to change the code to do that. Thanks again for the help!!!

Comment: Well, that line turns the dates into integers.

Comment: Do you want to just remove the borders or any other formatting as well?

Comment: Just the borders. Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy the columns out individually, as objects that refer to ranges require the cells to be in order.

Something like this should work:

```
activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("C:C").copy activeworkbook.Sheets(2).Columns("A:A")
activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("I:I").copy activeworkbook.Sheets(2).Columns("B:B")
activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("H:H").copy activeworkbook.Sheets(2).Columns("C:C")
activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("F:F").copy activeworkbook.Sheets(2).Columns("D:D")
```

then you should be able to do:

```
activeworkbook.Sheets(2).Columns("A:D").copy
```

to get it to the clipboard

Comment: Shouldn't it be the reverse? I mean Copy C ~~> A and similarly for the rest? Also you have a typo in the second line "B:A"?

Comment: Oops, yes, it should be the other way around (fixed typo too)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this method as well as it is a bit more simplistic.