# Using VBA to filter a table and copy certain columns to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table Named "Combined" which is stored on one sheet of a work book.

On a second sheet I have the following Cell Range (in `C1:F2`)

```
Delivery    | Column Ref | Column Ref | Available
Delivery ID | I          | J          | YES
```

I want to be able to use VBA to filter the table based on the values in this cell range

The Data drop column is a cell with a drop down list which uses `VLOOKUP` to populate the two column ref cells.  These are the two columns that need to be filtered.

Column `I` needs to show all rows that `<>"X"` while column `J` needs to show all rows that equal the value in the available column.

I then need to be able to copy columns `A`,`G` and the column that appears in the first reference cell to cell `A5` in the second sheet.

Is it possible to do this using VBA?  I have been attempting to do this using IF statements, but it is very messy.

I have a piece of code I am attempting to modify [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303770/vba-filter-table-and-copy-subset-of-resulting-columns-to-clipboard)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim rRange As Range, rngToCopy As Range
    Dim lRow As Long    
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    Dim lCol As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")

    With ws

        '~~> Set your range for autofilter
        Set rRange = .Range("A1:AR" & lRow2)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Filter, copy visible rows to temp sheet
        With rRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="X"

            '~~> This is required to get the visible range
            ws.Rows("1:lRow2").EntireRow.Hidden = True

            Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

            Set wsTemp = Sheets.Add

            rngToCopy.Copy wsTemp.Range("A1")

            '~~> Unhide the rows
            ws.Rows("1:lRow").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But I do not know how to modify the `With rRange` section to meet my needs (i.e, Column I <>"X" and column J=F2

Additionally this line  `ws.Rows("1:lRow2").EntireRow.Hidden = True` is giving me a type mismatch error

[example of combined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov3vR.png)

---

UPDATE

So my code now looks like this thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531128/copy-paste-calculate-visible-cells-from-one-column-of-a-filtered-table)

```
    Sub AddFilter()
'
' AddFilter Macro
'

Dim rCrit1 As Range, rCrit2 As Range, rCrit3 As Range
Dim copyRange1 As Range, copyRange2 As Range, copyRange3 As Range
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")

lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:Z" & lastRow)
Set copyRange1 = src.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
Set copyRange2 = src.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
Set copyRange3 = src.Range("I2:I" & lastRow)

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set rCrit1 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_1")
Set rCrit2 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_2")
Set rCrit3 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_3")

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:C3").ClearContents
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:C3").ClearFormats

Selection.AutoFilter
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit1, Criteria1:="<>X"
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit2, Criteria1:=rCrit_3

copyRange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A5")
copyRange2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("B5")
copyRange3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("C5")

End Sub
```

However the filterRange.Autofilter line is not reading the rCrit_3 value correctly and so is not filtering based on this (Ref_3 is a named range which contains the YES cell in the first part of the problem).

Additionally the copyRange lines are giving me '1004' runtime error, but if I minimise the spreadsheet and run the code from the VBA window, it will run error free.

Can anyone shed some light on these issues?

Comment: 1) It would be helpful if you could add some sample data from the `Combined` table to your question. 2) Is it important for Excel to show the data as filtered? Or do you just want the results on a separate worksheet?

Comment: I have added an example table to the original question.  I am looking to get the results on a separate worksheet.  I have seen VBA code for filtering then copying a range so was attempting to do that without success, however if a direct insertion of the results is possible I canuse that option too.